# Developing Unity game on Windows for iOS devices

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

My unity application is developed for iOS devices, but for some reason at this moment I have only Windows PC.

I searched around and found similar information, but not clear for what I want.
My query is 
I will do development of the game in Windows PC using C#.
Then will build and deploy to iOS device using MAC.
Is that possible? I like to make sure.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to build for iOS on Windows. But it is possible to build for Windows or Android on iOS. Thats what i know atleast.

Comment: Not the question, he want to import his project, to build it on a mac. Also, iOs is the mobile OS, you meaned MacOS.

Comment: Yes, i've read the question totally wrong. Thanks

Comment: It's possible to develop on windows, and build and deploy by mac.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have made several Unity3D projects for iOS using a Windows.

When installing Unity, don't forget to check "iOS deployment" and your Unity (on Windows) will be able to build an Xcode project.

Then, just transfer this Xcode project on a Mac with Xcode installed and you will be able to compile the project in order to be run on your iOS device.

Note : I just have to run `chmod 777 MapFileParser.sh` on the Mac folder containing the Xcode project before compiling with Xcode.

Comment: Or he can use Unity cloud to build the ipa and he will only need a mac to publish the app on the app store.

Comment: I am wondering who downvoted the answer and for which reason. The OP asked if it was possible to develop iOS application on a Windows and I gave my experience and how I do it.

Comment: @Rostin : I didn't say my answer is the only way to go, I indicate I do it myself. You can post an answer indicating how to do it using Unity Cloud, I'm curious since I've never used it.

Comment: I did post an answer on how to use Unity Cloud... if it's not descriptive enough let me know.

Comment: My guess to the downvote was that this method still needs a Mac. Unfortunate, but true (it's also how *I* did it).

Comment: You don't need the map parser if you zip it first and its semi small at that point. It's annoying that you can use the same bridge that Visual Studio uses. I ended creating a batch file that pushed and deployed. In the end I have my project in Azure Devops and use Cake for automatic deployments via AppCenter. Basically free.

Comment: You can also use the App Center Build and deploy from your Git repo, but I don't trust MS to be up all the time as they take down App Center for no reasons for hours at a time frequently

Answer (score 2):

You can always use Unity Cloud to build you games. Their server will build it either from your own repo (git, svn, etc) or you can use their Collaborate feature by going into the unity editor -> services -> collaborate on.

Before getting to use Unity Cloud to build for iOS, you will need to generate your certificates just as you do when building using XCode. On the config page you can choose the version of unity you want the build to use, the version of xcode and if you want Unity to build your game on every push ( auto-build).

[image]

As far as I know when building for ios the ipa will have a ridiculous size. If you encounter this problem please refer to the following link:  [how to disable bitecode](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-5-3-x-build-size-increase-faq.383533/)

Even though Unity allows us to use their system to build for any platform, in order to upload your *.ipa to app store you will need to do it through application loader.